# get my inputs inside my labels with CakePHP's FormHelper::radio() method

Tags: cakephp

I've looked quite thoroughly through previous questions and I'm surprised that nobody else has asked this yet because it seems like a pretty simple thing.

How do I make my labels wrap the inputs as well as the label text using CakePHP's FormHelper? I am using CakePHP 2.3.1. A call to `$this->Form->radio()` with some standard options yields:

```
<input id="input_id" type="radio" ... />
<label for="input_id">label text</label>
```

What I'm looking for is

```
<label for="input_id"><input type="radio" id="input_id" ... />label text</label>
```

I have achieved this *sort of* using:

```
$this->Form->input('input1',array('options'=>$options,'type'=>'radio',
    'label'=>false
    'before'=>'<label>',
    'separator'=>'</label><label>',
    'after'=>'</label>'
));
```

But obviously this solution is not ideal. Can anybody tell me if CakePHP has an easier and "more proper" way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend the helper, and make your own method.

```
<?php
// app/views/helpers/radio.php
class RadioHelper extends AppHelper {

    function display($id, $options = array()) {
        if (isset($options['options']) && !empty($options['options'])) {
            $rc = "";
            foreach ($options['options'] as $option) {
                $rc .= "<label>";
                $rc .= "<input ....>";
                $rc .= "</label>";
            }
            return($rc);
        }
        return(false); // No options supplied.
    }
}

?>
```

---

```
<?php

// some_controller.php
var $helpers = array('Radio');

?>
```

---

```
<?php 

// some_view.ctp
echo $this->Radio->display('input1', array('options' => $options));

?>
```

Just make sure you copy the logic from the form helper into your own helper here...

P.S. if you're just adding a single method, it's not likely you'll need an entire helper. Just add the function "display" to app_helper.php and reference it from any "other" helper you already loaded, since they extend app_helper, you'll have the display method available in all the child helpers.

Comment: I just noticed you said you were working with cake 2.3.1, which is a little different, but the concept is still the same.

Answer (score 14):

I came across this whilst trying to find the answer myself and solved it. You don't need to alter/extend the class; it can be acheived purely through passing the appropriate options.

This is what I did so it works with bootstrap:

```
$options = array(
           '1' => 'One',
           '2' => 'Two'
           );
$attributes = array(
            'class' => '',
            'label' => false,
            'type' => 'radio',
            'default'=> 0,
            'legend' => false,
            'before' => '<div class="radio"><label>',
            'after' => '</label></div>',
            'separator' => '</label></div><div class="radio"><label>',
            'options' => $options
            );

echo $this->Form->input('myRadios', $attributes);
```

This will put each radio in its own `<div class="radio">` to comply with bootstrap markup. If you just want the simple label wrapping remove the `div` elements from `before`, `after` and `separator`